# Export large amount of data using Laravel Excel getting timed out error

Tags: php, excel, laravel

I must export over 10k records to Excel from a database using the Maatwebsite Laravel Excel 3.1 package. It working fine with small amount of data (less than 10k). I am using job and chunk in the export class. but I got a time-out error. My limit is 512M.

```
namespace App\Exports;

use App\Events\Download\DownloadComplete;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Responsable;
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Exportable;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromQuery;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ShouldAutoSize;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithCustomChunkSize;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithEvents;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithMapping;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithTitle;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Events\AfterSheet;
use App\Traits\ReportDownloadTrait;
use Throwable;
use App\PreDownloadData;

class ReportExport implements FromQuery, WithHeadings, ShouldAutoSize, Responsable, WithEvents, WithTitle, WithMapping, WithCustomChunkSize, ShouldQueue
{
    use Exportable, ReportDownloadTrait;

    protected array $headings, $inputs;
    protected int $download_id;

    public $fileName = "report_download.xlsx";
    public $timeout = 1200; // 5 hour
    public $tries = 3;

    public function query()
    {
        return DownloadData::whereDownloadId($this->download_id)->whereNotNull('row');
    }

    public function map($data): array
    {
        return $data->row;
    }

    public function batchSize(): int
    {
        return 200;
    }

    public function chunkSize(): int
    {
        return 200;
    }

    public function headings(): array
    {
      [];
    }
```

Comment: Update your job timeout configuration in your config/queue.php file. For example, set the timeout to a higher value like 1800 (30 minutes): 'timeout' => 1800,

Comment: try increasing it further in your php.ini or .htaccess file: memory_limit = 1024M

Comment: I have already tried with 18000 (5 hrs) and memory limit 1024M.but get same error.lluminate\Queue\MaxAttemptsExceededException: Maatwebsite\Excel\Jobs\AppendQueryToSheet has been attempted too many times or run too long

Comment: Any other option like data fetching using multiple jobs and write to excel after complete each job.?after all job completed ,download the created excel file.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust your query method to use chunking directly without relying on the batchSize and chunkSize in the export class.

```
DownloadData::whereDownloadId($this->download_id)
    ->whereNotNull('row')
    ->chunk(200, function ($data) {
        foreach ($data as $row) {
            // Process each row of data here
            // For example, you might export the row to a CSV file
            fputcsv($file, $row->toArray());
        }
    });
```

In this example, the chunk method retrieves 200 rows of data at a time from the database. For each chunk, it loops over the rows of data and exports each row to a CSV file. The $file variable would be a file handle resource that you've opened using the fopen function.

Comment: Hi @karl Hill Thank you for your valuable time.What id do inside chunk function...?i am new comer in laravel..